# Как достать полную фотографию профиля. Instagram

Tags: php, api, instagram

Есть разные сервисы например http://izuum.com которые предоставляют возможность получить фотографию профиля пользователя с высоким разрешением.

Все ссылки на изображение от них ведут на сайт https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com

Полная ссылка выглядит так:

https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/0ffa6fe043b574c5e99d6850e5fa1732/5E19CBD6/t51.2885-19/36928545_502762873494611_5185555303428521984_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com

Что я пробовал: https://www.instagram.com/shumik_ua/?__a=1 по этой ссылке можно получить много информации, в т.ч. ссылки на сильно уменьшенное изображение, и немного. Но это не то, что мне нужно.

Второй вариант - https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/2346458556/info/ - сдесь есть нужная мне ссылка в параметре hd_profile_pic_url_info.

*примечание, в ссылке сайт https://instagram.flwo1-1.fna.fbcdn.net

Но есть проблема: весь json можно получить только если перейти с браузера. Я использовал file_get_contents, curl, со всеми нужными параметрами, такими как user_agent, использование cookie. Мне в любом случае возвращает упрощенный вариант json, не полный. Там нет той ссылки.

Еще один нюанс. Оба запроса возвращают изображения с сайта https://instagram.flwo1-1.fna.fbcdn.net, а вот все сторонние сервисы, как я упоминал раньше - с https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com. Это значит, что есть способ, о котором я не знаю.

Если кто-то знает/читал как еще можно реализовать - пожалуйста отпишитесь, буду благодарен

Comment: второй вариант возвращает небось данные, когда вы авторизованы в инстаграме в браузере. просто так он данное поле не возвращает.

Comment: @teran да, реально. Спасибо большое) Теперь хоть понимаю почему не работало